# FireFox not computing / applying certain css

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have a very odd bug. I have a css class, which I apply to all list items of an unordered list. In chrome everything works as it should. In firefox, however, some list items have the class applied and some don't. What is more, when I inspect computed css with firebug, I see that on some items, the class was not computed, but they look like it did (they have class defined colors, fonts etc). And on other items, it's neither loaded and computed nor applied.

```
.menu-item > a:visited {
    background-color: #006890;
    color: #FFF !important;
}



   <ul> 
      <li class="menu-item"> <a href="something"> link </a> </li>
      <li class="menu-item"> <a href="something"> other link </a> </li> 
   </ul>
```

And when I click the link which redirects me to somewhere, the class is not applied, and the link looks the same

Comment: the given style will only apply to links which point at a url you have already visited with the current browser. (I did not downvote you). When you want a style to apply to all items of the list, you may use this selector: `.menu-item > a`

Comment: Targeting `a:visited` will only apply the styles to visited anchors

Comment: yes i know, but nothing is applied even after the link is clicked. My bad, should've pointed that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: a:visited has been disabled in firefox due to security reasons, that is why the class wasn't applied.

Answer (score 0):

Your style work only for links which point at url you have already visited with the current browser ..

when you want a style to apply to all items of the list, you may use this selector: `.menu-item > a`

Comment: I only want my style to work for the visited links. But even after the link is clicked, the styles are not applied, and this only happens in firefox

Comment: you want prefix with browser prefix like --moz then

Comment: My styles are related to font and background prefixed, firefox should definitely support those.